# How to interact with android keyboard enter and rest of the button

Tags: android

I have an edit box which popup an android keyboard. What i want is on click of done button in the keyboard i want to display a message in the and if the user click rest of the buttons in-spite of done button the message should be clear. I have used this code but it doesn't work. Please help me to solve this out.

**Code i have used**

```
m_passwrdEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {           
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {                             
                m_passwrdErrorText.setText("Test Project");
            }
            else 
            {                   
                m_passwrdErrorText.setText("");
            }

            m_passwrdEditText.setTypeface(face);
            return false;
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

return `true` from `onKey()` method.